# karnaugh table issues

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic

[image]

Hello,I have this truth table.I did this table and I am creating a demultiplexer 1 in 2.Not multiplexer.
Second,I did [image]

and that [image]

I gave and those [image]

Am I right?I want to confirm that I have done it all right

Comment: Your first truth table is for the demux right? Then you tried to split it up into two separate truth tables, one for each output? If so, how come Out2 doesn't match anything at all? All you had to do was copy down a part of your original truth table just like you did with Out1.

Comment: I tried to do that with karnaugh. I use the Out2=In*~Sel. I don't know if I am right at that..that's I came here to ask where did I go wrong

Comment: Where is Karnaugh coming in? You aren't at the point where you are doing any Karnaugh yet. Split the original truth table into two: one for each output and THEN do Karnaugh on each one to get the expression for Out1 and OUt2.

Comment: I didn't get you.On out2 is my issue I think.

Comment: so you mean I don't change anything on out1 and out2 ?right?

Comment: What made you decide to do something differently for Out2 than for Out1? Why did you not just do exactly the same process? You did it correctly for Out1, so why did you suddenly go and do something different for Out2? Just do the same thing again.

Comment: thank you a lot I thought I should have change it. Again thank you and if you could offer me some more informations (links about multiplex-demultiplex design I would appreciate)

Comment: For demux to two outputs , you only need 1 bit and the input signal so basically an inverter with 2 And gates sharing the input. A simple truth table will tell you this to choose a binary address to equal the output port #. No karnaugh map reduction is necessary with simplicity.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 what?You mean I am wrong or you confirm what DKNguyen said?

Comment: He's saying you don't need to do a K-map at all because it's so simple you can just look at the truth table and write the equation directly.

Comment: so my equations are wrong?

Comment: @Yun.kon Your equations look fine. Your out2 table is insane: 3 '1's? There should only be 1. (Unless you didn't write up the headers correctly.)

Comment: @jonk thanks ,I have re-doing it ,but again thank you :)

Comment: @Yun.kon No problem. I'm glad to see you are actually trying hard to get things right and asking for help while at the same time providing your work product.  Not only that, but you respond to is. Very nice to see. I'll +1 your question, now.

Answer (score 0):

Out1 is correct. This is what Out2 should be:

[image]

Although, as Tony mentioned, to make the circuit a Karnaugh table is really not needed: It's a, "demux to two outputs, you only need one bit and the input signal (basically an inverter with two AND-gates sharing the input). [...] Choose a binary address to equal the output port #."